# Repeating a prompt in ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, conditional-statements, devops, prompt

I am now working on ansible 2.6 and I want to repeat an action until a specific condition is respected.

Example:

```
- vars_prompt: 
- name: apache_quest_ext
  prompt: 
    "Voulez vous installer des extensions pour apache ? [y/n]"
  private: no
```

I would like to repeat the question until user enter no.

Comment: Try registering your result und use `until` as well to make the prompt get repeated until the answer is `no`

Comment: I have already try this way, it doesn't work